# The review process for edits in community wikis needs improvement

Tags: feature-request, edits, review

Any review process in professional environments allows rebuttals or some kind of reply in order to explain the edit. The simple one round voting system to accept or reject an edit has many drawbacks if the voters are not qualified enough to judge if an edit is good or not. This turns down the quality of many posts.

Comment: So, what's you suggestion? What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this post? You tagged as [meta-tag:feature-request], yet no features have been requested.

Comment: If they're not qualified to judge then they shouldn't be accepting or rejecting; that's why there's a "skip" option. I'm not sure there's a way to force people to actually use it, though.

Comment: I suggest a feature for the review process to reply to the voters. Now, there's no way to communicate with them, like I do here with you (that would be enough). It's normal the reviewers make mistakes. There's no system here to handle this.

Comment: Even if there was such a feature, I believe it would see little use, and some of the use it would see would end up being... ab-use.

Comment: If we add reviewer review, then we need to add reviewer reviewer review, and that just gets messy.

Comment: What kind of abuse. I just write to the voters. Nobody else could see the rebuttal. I'm working in research/science and there the whole evaluation system of publications is based on reviews and rebuttals. We don't need to invent new things, just see what has proven to be valuable already.

Comment: @Degread the problem with an open rebuttal system is based on the anonymous nature of the internet.  In a truly professional or academic setting, there will be *some* measure of professionalism and/or decorum to keep things in check.  On sites like SO, you just open it up for any troll who wants to argue his rejection.  While I can see some use for it, the negatives will far outweigh the benefits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming this feature request is based on your attempts to edit an answer to [The definitive guide to form-based website authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-forms-based-website-authentication/477578#477578) as you have 3 suggested edits within the last 4 hours, all being rejected:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2272030
2. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2273170
3. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2273246

Based on the standards established within the community, all 3 rejections were perfectly valid because you were trying to change the meaning of the answer, first by entering a note into the post, and then by trying to delete the info you tried to refute in your note.

I realize you are new to the community and you might not be aware of the ins and outs of how we like to handle things, but it has been decided through lots of discussion and through lessons learned on past mistakes that edits that change the meaning of a post are generally frowned upon (and this includes Community-wiki questions).

The best course of action in a case like this is to leave a comment (which unfortunately you can't do until you have at least 50 reputation), or leave your own answer (which you can normally do, except this specific question requires you to have at least 10 reputation.

Obviously you are very passionate about this specific situation, and we love the passion.  If you feel that strongly about this topic, then try to answer some other questions or leave some good edits, get your rep up to 10 and then write your own answer to include your information, and let the community decide for themselves whether to upvote it or not.

Comment: wait, surely community wiki means "feel free to add points and expand this answer" which could change the meaning. Do reviewers see that a post is CW?

Comment: @Kate I'm trying to remember. I don't think I've seen one due to the lower editing threshold.  I do agree with you in theory, but editing to change "don't do x" to "do x" is probably nit the intention if the relaxed rules

Answer (score 2):

There is a rebuttal process. Well, kind of. You can come to Meta.

If you find that you have made an excellent edit, but you can't for the life of you figure out why anyone would reject it, ask us.

If it's a good edit, someone might make it for you. Or we'd tell you to make it again and try to be the reviewers for it. And if it truly should have been rejected, we can tell you why.

Adding in a rebuttal system to go back and forth with those who reviewed, within the context of Stack Overflow, seems pointless. I'm hard-pressed to believe that it will have many positive results.

Comment: If it works like this its fine. But it's not that obvious to post it here, or? It's not a bug, a feature, or meta discussion topic. I have to search for it. It's not an easy going way or system. Just allow one single line of reply to the voters so that they can change their mind. Totally simple. In research it's usually about three rounds. Anyway, I give up. If it's so difficult to improve stackoverflow posts, then I simply do not edit anymore.

Comment: @Degread In an academic setting rebuttals are already hardly successful in my experience. In the online setting of Stack Overflow I think it's even less likely to succeed. Users generally don't reverse their downvotes, nor are they likely to see the light if you tell them how their rejection is mistaken. Even if you don't do so in the form of a rant. As far as edits go, you win some, you lose some. I wouldn't let that stop me from editing, but that decision is entirely yours.

Comment: Good or not, in an academic setting rebuttals are the only evaluation system to decide if a paper should be published or not. But I get the point: "Users generally don't reverse their downvotes,"

Answer (score 0):

The post requirements are clearly stated in the help center.

The suggested-edit rejection notes are clearly stated when the rejection is given.

After carefully studying the documentation and rejection reason, an editor can usually submit a new, improved edit. Any additional person-to-person communication has the potential to lead to extended conversation and/or debate which is carefully avoided on SO.

Comment: Line two: That's not the point. Even professionals could be wrong and reject because of wrong reasons. Line three: The problem is that in each round different reviewers do the voting. So if its a more complicated issue its likely they don't get the point. (E.g. I submitted three times, nobody got the point - I gave up)

Comment: While mistakes are possible, an edit requires three approvals or rejections before moving forward. It is unlikely that three established users will be wrong where a single, less established user is right.